# Making a presence/absence matrix from two files using python

Tags: python

I have the following two files:

(a):

```
A01
A02
A03
A10
A11
C03
C10
C11
E01
E10
E11
H01
H02
H10
H11
Y09
Y10
Y11
```

and

(b):

```
E01  Y09  A02
A01  A03
C03  H01  H02
E10
Y10
A10
C10
H10
E11  A11  C11  H11  Y11
```

I am trying to make a presence/absence matrix from this data to see if the values in (a) are present in the lines in (b). If they are present then they should be represented by a "1" and if not, they should be represented by a "0", where the "0" and "1" indicators following the sequence of the values in (a).

My expected output would be:

```
0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1
```

I have tried the following:

```
text_file = open("Table", "w")
a = file("list", "r")
b = file("cluster", "r")

for line in a:
    words = line.split("\n")
for line in b:
    words = line.split("\t")


for line in a:
    if words in a == words in b:
        print("1")
    elif words in a != words in b:
        print("0")
text_file.close
```

However this does not print anything.

Can anybody help?

Comment: What do you specifically mean "are present in the lines of (b)"? I am having a hard time finding the pattern here.

Comment: It would help to know what are the row and column names ;)

Comment: Hi @Malonge, in file (a) there will only be one column with one word per line, in file (b) there will be multiple columns (with one word per column) per line in (b), each line in (b) will have a varying number of columns. So, I want to see if a value (per line) in (a) is present in any of the lines in (b). Is this more clear? :)

Comment: Your expected output is a matrix of 9 rows and 18 columns. How was its size determined?

Comment: It looks like the rows match the number of lines in file b while the columns match the number of lines in fine a.

Comment: Hi @martineau, there are 18 rows in (a) which correspond to the 18 columns and there are 9 rows in (b) which are expressed as the 9 rows in the output file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This produces the desired output from the two input files:

```
with open('list', 'rt') as list_file:
    values = [line.strip() for line in list_file]

with open('cluster', 'rt') as cluster_file, open('Table', 'wt') as table_file:
    for cluster in (set(line.split()) for line in cluster_file):
        row = ' '.join('01'[value in cluster] for value in values)
        table_file.write(row + '\n')
```

Comment: Thank you so much, @Martineau!

Answer (score 2):

I think I understand what you want here.

```
final_matrix = []
a = file("list", "r")
a_list = []
# Make a list of all strings in the first file.
for line in a:
    a_list.append(line.rstrip())

b = file("cluster", "r")
for line in b:
    L1 = line.split('\t')
    # Make a presence/absence row for each line in the second file.
    this_row = [1 if i in L1 else 0 for i in a_list]
    final_matrix.append(this_row)

for row in final_matrix:
    print row
    # You can get fancier with this because right now it will
    # Print these out as lists.
```

In this case, the final matrix is saved as a list of lists.

Comment: Thanks for this, @Malonge! I can see your logic behind this. However, when I try to run this I get no output; do you know why this could be?

Comment: Well right now there is no printing involved. Just print out the final_matrix. I will add to my code to help you out.

Comment: Thank you very much, @Malonge! this is exactly what I'm looking for! I tried to save this as an outfile (by adding "text_file = open("Table", "w")" to the beginning and "text_file.write(row)" and "text_file.close()" to the end of the file however this doesn't save the file, would you happen to have any suggestions about how to fix this? Thanks again!